# Export AngularJS table to .CSV directing to about:blank page?

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs, node.js, excel

I currently have a Javascript function which exports my AngularJS table of JSON data to a .csv file by div ID as shown:

```
$scope.exportToExcel = function (tableId) { // ex: '#my-table'
    var exportHref = Excel.tableToExcel(tableId, 'WireWorkbenchDataExport');
    $timeout(function () { location.href = exportHref; }, 100); // trigger download
}
```

Which I call like so

```
<button style="float: right;" class="btn btn-link" ng-click="exportToExcel('#codeProjectsTable')" filename="test.csv">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share"></span>
      Export table
</button>
```

This works well for data sets with ~400 records or less (20 columns per record), but I'm trying to export nearly 1,000 records for further reporting and I am simply being directed to an *about:blank* page.

I'm suspecting that it is either

1. Unable to export this large of a file
2. Timing out because of a long request

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I used following logic for to export

```
            var fileName = 'users_export_' + moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD') + '.csv';
            var url = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
            var a = document.createElement('a');
            a.href = url;
            a.download = fileName;
            a.target = '_blank';
            a.click();
```

And its working for large for large file/data

Comment: How is your `response.data` coming in? JSON format?

Comment: no its not in  json format . In normal text like a table

Comment: Thanks.  Can you show me how you're returning your response object please?  I tried JSON and it grabs the DOM source so there is a lot of uncalled for data.  I also tried by table ID and it is undefined.